# completely replace an HTML file with another using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, replace

I am working on a html form, which I only want to be usable once at all.
So if one person has filled it in, another person should not be able to fill it in again. Not even the same person, and not even if he or she clicks on going back in his or her browser.

So far I have multiple ways in mind what could work:

1. Use PHP to completely replace the form.html page with another .html file, which I have already stored on the server for this purpose, or
2. Use PHP to partly replace the form.html page, even though it has no added value over completely replacing the html page, or
3. Adding a hidden field to my form.html file (which I have to change to a .php page in this case), posting a "1" to a database which I can retrieve everytime the form.php page loads in a way that it shows the form when a 0 is set, and doesn't when a 1 is set. In this case I also wonder if there isn't a simpeler solution to create a database just to store one "1".

I know how to use google, and usually I always manage to find a solution, but now I am feeling clueless. Please someone help me with a simple solution.

Comment: You mean this is a html form that can be only one time filled in? Or you mean one time from the same person ?

Comment: You should stop thinking of html forms as "html files" and trying to control their use by their physical storage on the server. That does not really work and is very clumsy. Remember that there are things like caches and proxies... Instead think of an html form as some piece of text some controller logic outputs. Not more, not less. So what you want to do is actually this: based on the history of how people used your application (stored in a database or such) your controller outputs different forms. That's easy and reliable.

Comment: @Basti This is a html form that can be only one time filled in.

Comment: @arkascha thnx, but I only need a simple solution for this to work.

Comment: Switching the output certainly is much simpler than replacing files...

Answer (score 0):

I have used the rename command at the end of my mail script, and this way it works:

```
mail($to, $subject, $comment, $headers);
rename('../mailtest/replace/emailform.html', '../mailtest/emailform.html');
?>
```

Comment: This is insecure, since it cannot protect from requests to the file before having actually processed the previous submitted form. So several clients can request and load the form until the first one submits and thus triggers the replacement of the physical file. This means all other clients are left with the "outdated" form which is still valid and usable...

Comment: ah that way, I understand. I send the variables through two scripts, so i will make this script also rename the first script with a redirect page, thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, fine if that solves your issue for you. Then all I want to add is: please keep in mind that your approach is highly unorthodox. It raises all sorts of security issues (which may not be relevant for you, granted) and is unnecessary insecure and costly (comparing file system operations to a simple conditional). So for the future you may want to take a look into how the MVC idea works and why it is the preferred and standard approach to such implementations.